# How to set an animation of images in background of table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

How do I programmatically set an image in the background of a table view cell? Can I animate it? Can I animate just a selected cell?

**Note**

I have used the `Answer your own question` feature to answer this question. Please, by all means add an answer if you've got other methods. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: GIF of Animated cell]

To programatically add a background image to your table view cell (both custom and default) it is easiest done in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

To set the background image, you need to create UIImageView reference, then assign that reference to an image. Then assign cell the UIImageView reference. This is done in the following code to have a default image throughout all cells in your tableview:

```
//have normal background image
//Create a UIImageView the size of your tableview row. My row (cell) size is 55 and I want it to expand the full length of the window (iPhone). 
//You can create an icon look if you like, just play with the sizing. 
UIImageView * cellBackgrounds = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];

//Next create a reference to the image
UIImage * regularImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];

//assign the image to the UIImageView
cellBackgrounds.image = regularImage;

//set the ##background## of the cell
//cell has already been defined when you create the UITableViewCell * cell = ... code
[cell setBackgroundView: cellBackgrounds];
```

To animate the cell we do the same method except this time we refer to a set of images.

First we add a file to the project containing all the images we are going to display as an animation. To do this, simply drag the file into your Xcode project while Xcode is open and drop it in the left panel that contains all your .h and .m files. Make sure to name all your images in numerical order - image1, image2, image3, etc - before.

Then we use the following code. Notice the only change is the UIImage code:

```
//have animated background
UIImageView * cellBackgrounds = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];

//Change UIImage imageNamed to UIImage animatedImageNamed and refer to just the name of your images, not the number
//set the duration (which is in seconds) to whatever you like, testing to your desired flow 
UIImage * animatedImages = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image" duration:3.6];
cellBackgrounds.image = animatedImages;
[cell setBackgroundView: cellBackgrounds];
```

Now you have an animated table view cell background.

If you only want a selected row to be animated here's how you do it:

```
//Create a new reference to an index path
//I am referencing to the top cell in the first section
NSIndexPath *firstCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection:0];

//Create a new reference to the UITableViewCell
UITableViewCell *topCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:firstCell];
UIImageView * cellBackgrounds = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
UIImage * animatedImages = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image" duration:3.6];
cellBackgrounds.image = animatedImages;
[cell setBackgroundView: cellBackgrounds];
```

This new code will prevent the text you're trying to display from displaying properly so add this to bottom of this block of code to ensure the text displays properly

```
topCell.title.text = your reference to Strings to be displayed
```

Enjoy.

Comment: All true, except if you're using the dequeue functionality, to save memory, you really should be doing most of this in `willDisplayCell`.

Comment: Probably best to get the bounds of the screen width and to display correctly on wider screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


//1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
CATransform3D rotation;
rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;


//2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
cell.alpha = 0;

cell.layer.transform = rotation;
cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);


//3. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
cell.alpha = 1;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```