# Animated Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am making an app in which there are two buttons in the center. The background is there and I need the background to have an animation. With that said I mean like little raindrops constantly falling in the background. I have no clue on how to do this. My customer really, really wants this. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't "write your features for you overflow" :)

Comment: **I was providing details**

Comment: It's important that your question display at least a basic effort at solving the problem, or the research you've conducted trying to find the answer. See [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Take a course on CoreAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the images are named in numerical order with the number at the end of the name. Then drag and drop the file of images into your Xcode folder area. Then you reference **only** the image name and **not** the number in `animatedImageNamed`.

You need to create an ImageView the size of the Background for each device you plan on using.

```
//place this in your viewDidLoad
UIImageView * background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
UIImage * image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"MovingCar" duration:3.6];
background.image = image;
[self.view setBackgroundView: background];
```

You can change the duration to suit your needs accordingly.

Comment: I am doing this with swift. It is giving me 2 errors.   `UIImageView * background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 55)];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"Right" duration:3.6];
        background.image = image;
        [self.view setBackgroundView: background];`

Comment: That code will create frame animation (which is sort of like a flip book, where it flips through the frames one at a time.) It won't animate images across the screen.

Comment: Do you know how to make it look like there are rain drops dropping down the screen? In swift?

Comment: It does animate the images providing the images are created in a sequence and at an appropriate size. It is in Obj-C. The frame size is also something that should be changed. You need to create the images yourself in Photoshop or another graphic editing program and and ensire the background is a size of say 320 wide X 768 high or whatever size you find fitting. But if you don't know that you need to have your own images then it's not going to work.

Comment: The code works as you will see here in the table view cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448440/how-to-set-an-animation-of-images-in-background-of-table-view-cell

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UIView method `animateWithDuration:animations:` or one of it's variants that has a completion method to animate images from the top to the bottom of the screen. Take a look at the Xcode docs on that method, and search the web for examples.

As the other poster says, this site is for helping people with problems, not for asking others to provide you with ready-made solutions.

I could bang out some animation code for you that would create an endless stream of falling raindrops, but it would probably take me a couple of hours to get it fully working, and I'd have to charge you for it. (Plus I'm not very familiar with Swift so I'd have to do some translation from Objective-C, which is my day-to-day programming language.)

Comment: Duncan C is the man. You will see his work all over the net. Honestly though, if you can not put in the effort to attempt to do this stuff, this is not the place to purchase the solution. Please see the user tour for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @The-Rooster hey you silly, you don't get it, he gives example, and don't be jealous.

Comment: @Andy What don't I get? What am I jealous of? I know the answer on how to do this so I see no reason as to why I would be jealous. Thanks for your valuable input, truly enlightening.

Comment: @The-Rooster, my point was that we're not here to provide solutions for free. Developing a falling drops animation is work. I'm happy to point the OP in the right direction, but it would take work on his/her part.

Comment: @DuncanC I was not attacking you, I am sorry if that was the impression I gave. I was agreeing with you. This site is for that very purpose - to help guide people who are willing to work towards a solution and not simply obtain the whole thing with no knowledge of what the answer means or how to use it.